Local compactness and Hausdorff
I've been stuck on this exercise from Theodore Gamelin's book 'Introduction to Topology' for a few days, and I need help.
The statement is:

If $X$ is a topological space such that for every point in $X$ there exists an open neighborhood $U$ such that $\overline{U}$ is a compact and Hausdorff space, then $X$ is Hausdorff.

This is what I have so far:
Let $p, q \in X$ be distinct points. I need to show the existence of open sets $A_p$ and $A_q$ containing $p$ and $q$ respectively, and that $A_p \cap A_q = \emptyset$.
By hypothesis, there are open sets $U_p$ and $U_q$ containing $p$ and $q$ respectively, such that $\overline{U_p}$ and $\overline{U_q}$ are compact and Hausdorff. It is necessary to observe that if $U_p$ and $U_q$ are disjoint, then there is nothing to prove, right? So we need to assume that $U_p \cap U_q \neq \emptyset$.
Since $\overline{U_p}$ is compact and Hausdorff, then $\overline{U_p}$ is regular (I have already proved this). Therefore, by the definition of regular, there are open sets in $\overline{U_p}$ that separate points and closed sets in $\overline{U_p}$. From there, I am lost. The hint given by the book is to consider the existence of disjoint open sets $V$ and $W$ in $\overline{U_p}$ such that $p \in V$, and $(\overline{U_p} \setminus U_p) \cup \lbrace q \rbrace \subset W$.
My question is:

I am assuming that $U_p \cap U_q \neq \emptyset$, but this does not necessarily mean that $q \in \overline{U_p}$. So how can $(\overline{U_p} \setminus U_p) \cup \lbrace q \rbrace \subset W$ be true if the open set $W$ is such that $W \subset \overline{U_p}$?


If $q\not\in \overline{U}_p$, then $q\in \overline{U_p}^c,$ which is open and disjoint from $U_p$

@AnneBauval I hadn't looked at your answer, I was simply looking at the question.

If $q\notin\overline{U_p}$, you are done: $U_p$ and $X\setminus\overline{U_p}$ are open sets separating $p,q$.
If $q\in\overline{U_p}$ then $K:=(\overline{U_p}\setminus U_p)\cup\{q\}$ is a closed subset of $\overline{U_p}$ and $p\notin K$, whence the existence of $V,W$ like in your hint (disjoint open sets $V$ and $W$ in the subspace $\overline{U_p}$ such that $p\in V$ and $K\subset W$).

Since $V$ is open in $\overline{U_p}$ and disjoint from $\overline{U_p}\setminus U_p$, it is an open subset of $U_p$ hence of $X$.
$W=O\cap\overline{U_p}$ for some open subset $O$ of $X$, and $O\cap V=W\cap V=\varnothing$, which ends the proof.


Thanks for your help!
And... I really don't got it why your answer received a downvote.
